# Clojure spec maps

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

Having two following specs:

```clj
(s/def ::x keyword?)
(s/def ::y keyword?)
(s/def ::z keyword?)

(s/def ::a
  (s/keys :req-un [::x
                   ::y]
          :opt-un [::z]))

(s/def ::b
  (s/map-of string? string?))
```

how do I combine `::a` and `::b` into `::m` so the following data is valid:

```clj
(s/valid? ::m
           {:x :foo
            :y :bar
            :z :any})

(s/valid? ::m
          {:x :foo
           :y :bar})

(s/valid? ::m
          {:x :foo
           :y :bar
           :z :baz})

(s/valid? ::m
          {:x :foo
           :y :bar
           :z "baz"})

(s/valid? ::m
          {:x :foo
           :y :bar
           :t "tic"})
```

additionally, how do I combine `::a` and `::b` into `::m` so the following data is invalid:

```clj
(s/valid? ::m
          {"r" "foo"
           "t" "bar"})

(s/valid? ::m
          {:x :foo
           "r" "bar"})

(s/valid? ::m
           {:x :foo
            :y :bar
            :r :any})
```

Neither of :

```clj
(s/def ::m (s/merge ::a ::b))

(s/def ::m (s/or :a ::a :b ::b))
```

works (as expected), but is there a way to match map entries in priority of the spec order?

The way it should work is the following:

1. take all the map entries of the value (which is a map)
2. partition the map entries into two sets. One confirming the `::a` spec and the other conforming the `::b` spec.
3. The two sub-maps should conform each the relevant spec as a whole. E.g the first partition should have all the required keys.

Comment: Why would `{"r" "foo" "t" "bar"}` be invalid? It conforms to the `::b` spec?

Comment: It wouldn't be valid as it conforms ONLY to `::b` spec. I want to define a spec which would conform to both `::a` AND `::b`. E.g `::a` a requires `:x` and `:y` and optionally when `:z` is present it must be a `keyword`. Additionally `::m` allows for arbitrary keys in the map as long as they are strings and their values are strings as well.

Comment: This sounds not like AND to me, since "all keys must be string" from ::b violates the keywords from ::a. I also see being `:t "tic"` be valid. So it's either ":x, :y, and maybe :z" OR anything with string keys and values.

Comment: @cfrick thank you very much for your comments. If you are saying, I haven't formulated my problem clearly and correctly you are absolutely right. To be honest I don't know how to express it clearly. I hope that the examples I included do help to understand my need. If you could reformulate my question to be clearer I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by treating the map not as a map but as a collection of map entries, and then validate the map entries. Handling the "required" keys part has to be done by s/and'ing an additional predicate.

```
(s/def ::x keyword?)
(s/def ::y keyword?)
(s/def ::z keyword?)

(s/def ::entry (s/or :x (s/tuple #{::x} ::x)
                     :y (s/tuple #{::y} ::y)
                     :z (s/tuple #{::z} ::z)
                     :str (s/tuple string? string?)))

(defn req-keys? [m] (and (contains? m :x) (contains? m :y)))

(s/def ::m (s/and map? (s/coll-of ::entry :into {}) req-keys?))
```